# What are the common phrases available to casually say I'm moving to a grocery?

Tags: phrase-request

What are the common phrases available to casually say "I'm moving to a grocery"?

Answer (score 2):

**Moving to** in English has an idiomatic usage which means *changing one's residence to*. It would be unusual for most people to say that they intend to take up residence in a grocery, and it would be equally unusual if the statement were casual.

A native English speaker would express the thought as:

> I'm moving to a grocery!

A likely response would be:

> Why? To be closer to the food?

I think that, instead, your question refers to ***going* to *the* grocery**. We would use the *definite article* **the** instead of the *indefinite article* **a** because the speaker, we assume, is going to a known and specific (definite) grocery. In that case, it might be expressed as:

> I'm going to the grocery.
>   I'm on my way to the grocery.
>   I'm heading to the grocery.
>   I'm off to the grocery.

If, instead, the speaker intends to go out and *find* a grocery, or if it is unimportant *which* grocery he visits, he might use the idefinite article:

> I'm going to **a** grocery.

The verbs **to move** and **to go** are not synonymous. Rely upon your dictionary for accurate definitions of these English verbs.

Comment: Thank you P.E Dant for explaination.
I also found people say "i'm on my way to the grocery"
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Not "moving to", but "going to".

Now in the UK, nearly all grocery shopping is done at supermarkets. Nearly all shops selling groceries would be better described as supermarkets, convenience stores, off-licences or petrol stations. The main shops that identify as "grocers" are shops selling ethnic food, eg Polish grocers.

So one would be more likely to say "I'm going to the supermarket", or "I'm going to Tesco" [a major supermarket brand]. Or simply "I'm going shopping."

*As the comment*
The "I'm going..." may mean that the actual movement towards the shop is in the future, but imminent. "I'm going shopping soon. Do you want anything?" If you wish to emphasise that you are already on the road, you could use "I'm on my way to the supermarket".

Comment: All true in the US, too, but we will sometimes use _grocery store_ in place of _supermarket_, even when it's a big mega-market. As in the UK, _grocery_ by itself as a noun (locale) sounds rare and quaint.

Comment: Grocers  (with or without an apostrophe) is the UK usage; "store" for "shop" is quite american, convenience store is a fairly recent borrowing. The corner  shops, that may have existed in my youth have been unable to compete, and sadly the days of [Open all hours](http://www.bbc.co.uk/comedy/openallhours/) have long past.  Also listen out for the possessive: "...going to Tesco's".

Comment: @JamesK Live and learn. This is my first encounter with "listen out." Is this a british usage? And surely you mean "long passed" - or is this another british usage?

Comment: No, just a mistake. Long passed is right